# How many simultaneous downloads make sense on iOS

Tags: ios, networking, afnetworking

I have an iOS app which synchronizes a certain number of assets at startup. I'm using AFNetworking and set up an NSOperationQueue to handle all of the downloads. I was wondering, how many simultaneous downloads make sense. Is there a limit where network performance will drop if I have to many at the same time? At the moment I'm doing max 5 downloads at a time.

Comment: depends on your speed rate (wlan, 3G or 4G) but 5 is a good number to deal with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on your hardware mostly I would say. Best way to address this is to test it with multiple cases with multiple trials. Try to diversify the hardware you test on as much as possible (remember do not use the simulator to test this!).

There actually is a [constant the SDK provides](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004592-RH2-SW12) that varies depending on various constraints. I would recommend you look into using it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out NSOperationQueueDefaultMaxConcurrentOperationCount--I had no idea that was in there!

Answer (score 5):

This depends on several factors:

- What is the network speed and latency?
- What is the data size of the requests and responses?
- How long does processing a request take on the server?
- How long does processing a response take on the client?
- How many parallel requests can the server fulfill efficiently?
- How many users will make requests at the same time?
- What is the minimal speed and memory size of the target device?

For small and medium sized applications, the limiting factor is usually the device's network latency, but that might not be the case in your situation. In the end, you'll have to test and figure out the most efficient compromise. 5 is a good number to start with. 
You might want to set the number of concurrent downloads by the available network connection (WLAN or 3G or even slower...).

Answer (score 4):

The beauty of using NSOperationQueues is that they are closely tied into the underlying OS (iOS or OSX). The queue decides how many operations to run based on many factors, including free memory, load on the system, etc.

You should not try to second guess the system and throttle yourself. Queue as many operations as you have and let the OS deal with it. I have an iPhone app that adds hundreds of operations in the queue when it has to fetch images of varying sizes etc. Works great, UI is not blocked, etc.

EDIT: well, it seems that when doing NSURLConnections and similar network connections, NSOperationQueue is NOT really keyed in to network usage. I asked on the Apple internal forums this summer, and in the end was told by Quinn "The Eskimo" (Apple network guru) to use a limit of something like 4. So this post is correct in the sense of pure processing power - NSOperationQueue will do the right thing - but when it comes to network ops you need to set a limit.

Comment: in my case i have 100 thumbnail images but the background threads didnot respond to my request and seems that the application get pause. I am using iPhone 3gs. if u have any idea please guide me..:)

Comment: @iPhoneNerd, see EDITed text above.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding this question, I've done some tests on a Ipad2 IOS6.0. I've created a little app that performs an HTTP-GET request to a webserver. This webserver will provide data for 60 seconds ( this to get a meaningfull result, will change this to 10 min later in my tests ).

For one HTTP-GET request it works very good. Then I tried to perform several HTTP-request at the same time and see how many and how fast I can download over a WIFI connection of the IPad

I made 2 versions. 1 version using NSOperations and 1 version using NSThread an Synchron HTTP-GET request. In short, I always get a TimeOut for my 6th request. ( The tcp-syn doesn't get to my HTTP-Server ).

### Extra info:

NSThead-implementation:

Simply make a for loop and create a Thread. This will perform a synchronized HTTP requests.

There I observe that my 6th request times out after 20 seconds. If I set the Timeout to 80 seconds, I clearly see that after the end of my first http-request ( after 60 seconds ) my 6th request is launched...

NSOperation-implementation:

Create a Queue and set the maxConcurrentOperations to 12. Add 12 http-request Operations to the queue. Here as well I notice that the 6th request gets a -1001 error code ( meaning: timout ). and I see no tcp-syn of the 6th request.

Comment: I am strugeling with a similar problem where my app only sends 5-6 requests and waits with the next request after the first one finished.